# Running multiple applications on Android Things

Tags: android-things

Can we install more than one application on *Android Things* and run only one at a time as we desire just like an app in *Android* phones?

Comment: Do you want to run two applications? Check this link out! [Is it possible to run multi applications at Android Things?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354646/6602159)

Comment: Where exactly is the problem with Raspberry Pi? You should better ask at https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ingo, _Android Things_ can currently run on 2 [hardwares](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms) only, one of which is _Raspberry Pi 3B_. So, I believe, OP runs the OS on the last mentioned.

Comment: @Onik Wasn't aware of this. Thanks for clarification :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Can we install more than one application on *Android Things* and run only one at a time as we desire just like an app in *Android* phones?

Yes, we can.

*Android Things* is yet *Android*. Although note that, in contrast to *Android*, *Android Things* does not have *System UI* app pre-installed, meaning no "Home screen" is available for users. So running other apps' launcher *Activities* would demand an extra effort (*those Activities should be `exported` to be launched either programmatically or through `adb`*).